# Development Server Crashing on Large Transaction in Fluent NHibernate

Tags: c#, sqlite, fluent-nhibernate, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a dictionary of ~50,000 words, each with has-many relationships to other words (synonyms, antonyms, etc). When I try a small sample of around 1000 words, it works just fine. When I do the entire data set, however, it quickly crashes the ASP.NET local development server.

```
List<Word> words;
...
using (var transaction = DatabaseSession.BeginTransaction())
{
    foreach (var word in words)
        MvcApplication.DatabaseSession.Save(word);
    transaction.Commit();
}
```

I'm on Windows 7 x64 using C#/.NET 4, ASP.NET MVC3, and Fluent NHibernate.

**Update**: It is actually crashing the WebDev server, not the database.

Comment: Could you define *crashes*? Are you getting an exception? Also SQLite is not thread safe and I am not sure that it is a good idea to use it in a multithreaded application.

Comment: Right, I am getting a stack overflow error from the server when I call Save. I'm not trying to use SQLite in production; I tried using MS SQL and it gives me the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by creating a console app to do the data uploading. I think the server was choking due to memory size.

Comment: You could reduce memory consumption be using IStatelessSession

Answer (score 0):

Change `ISession` to `IStatelessSession`. It should help and increase performance. Take a look at [this](http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2008/10/30/bulk-data-operations-with-nhibernate-s-stateless-sessions.aspx) and [this](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/08/22/nhibernate-perf-tricks.aspx).

Comment: When I change to using IStatelessSession, I get an error that the Word table doesn't exist when I call Insert. I'm pretty sure the table exists, because I am exporting the schema to the database on startup.